# URLs have an extra "w"

Tags: url

I have a weird problem: my EE URLs are generated with an extra "W". For instance, on `http://www.example.com`,

```
<a href="{path='article/details'}">{title}</a>
```

will produce (notice that www becomes wwww):

```
wwww.example.com/index.php/article/details/article-name
```

I can't find anything in the admin where I may have typed in the URL wrong.

Does anyone have an idea for how to solve this?

Comment: Can you provide more information. Where is the 'W'? Can you show some template code that displays a url with the extra 'W'? You haven't really given us much to go on.

Comment: <a href="{path='article/details'}">{title}</a>.
will produce: 
http://wwww.url.com/index.php/article/details/article-name

Comment: @TRiG it appears that the changes you made to the question have hidden the issue.

Comment: @zzzzBov, in the original question, both mentions of the domain were `wwww`. Perhaps that was a mistake. (The domain appeared only once in the rendered question, because of a Markdown error, but it was there in the source with a four-w prefix.)

Comment: @TRiG, the revision history shows you changing `wwww.url` to `www.example`, which is why I called out the issue.

Comment: Yes. In *both* cases, @zzzzBov. The original question *did not* show the domain changing. It used the same domain both times it was mentioned. The current version *does* show the domain changing. That's a significant difference. The original question had *one* domain name. After my edit, there was still *one* domain name. Now there are *two* domain names.

Answer (score 5):

Check the site url for your site in Admin->General Configuration

Also check this in your config file.

Comment: yep, i did. no go. also this is a msm site. the default site works fine. its the 2nd site that has problems.

Comment: found the issue. see my answer above...

Answer (score 2):

Found it. the issue was in the 2nd sites index.php file. the url was type wrong. Thanks foamcow for the help!!

Comment: You might mark foamcow's answer as the answer?